# To find same row in tic tac toe using a formula

Tags: python

I have numbered my tic-tac-toe game cells as:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Now, I want to create a formula or function (preferable formula) in Python such that when passed with a cell number, it gives a list of all cells of that row.

I created a formula for solving the same for the columns: `i`, `(i + 3) % 9` and `(i + 6) % 9`.

Similarly, I want a general expression for the rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar expression to create a row list. The code below creates both row and column lists using a pair of similar functions that both use the built-in `divmod()` function to convert the grid index into (X, Y) coordinates and a helper function `xy_to_i()` to convert such coordinates back into a grid index.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

grid = [range(i, i+3) for i in range(0, 9, 3)]

for row in grid: 
    print row
print

def xy_to_i(x, y): return 3 * (y % 3) + (x % 3)

def samerow(i):
    y, x = divmod(i, 3)
    return [xy_to_i(x + j, y) for j in (0, 1, 2)]

def samecol(i):
    y, x = divmod(i, 3)
    return [xy_to_i(x, y + j) for j in (0, 1, 2)]

for i in range(9):
    print i, samerow(i), samecol(i)
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]

0 [0, 1, 2] [0, 3, 6]
1 [1, 2, 0] [1, 4, 7]
2 [2, 0, 1] [2, 5, 8]
3 [3, 4, 5] [3, 6, 0]
4 [4, 5, 3] [4, 7, 1]
5 [5, 3, 4] [5, 8, 2]
6 [6, 7, 8] [6, 0, 3]
7 [7, 8, 6] [7, 1, 4]
8 [8, 6, 7] [8, 2, 5]
```

Now see if you can make a function that handles the diagonals properly. :)

Comment: thanks! it helped alot, I am trying for the diagonals now :)
This was the kind of solution I was looking for. :)

Comment: My pleasure, @AnishM! Good luck with the diagonals. Obviously, only even numbers can be in a diagonal. But you might want to make your diagonals function return an empty list or `None` if it's accidentally called with an odd number. I guess the tricky case is the center cell `4`, since it's in both the diagonals, so your diagonal function needs to return 2 lists in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For a square `n x n` grid, the indexes of the cells in the *row* containing index `i` are returned by:

```
def row_indexes(i, n):
    """
    Return the indexes or cells in the row containing index i for a
    n x n grid.
    """
    rowi = n * (i // 3)
    return list(range(rowi,rowi+n))
```

Similarly for *columns*:

```
def col_indexes(i, n):
    """
    Return the indexes or cells in the column containing index i for a
    n x n grid.
    """
    coli = i % n
    return list(range(coli, n*n, n))
```

(omit the `list()` if you're using Python 2, since `range` will already return you a list).

For example,

```
>>> row_indexes(5,3)
[3, 4, 5]
>>> col_indexes(5,3)
[2, 5, 8]
```